# HTML5 Canvas drag and drop line

Tags: javascript, json, html, canvas, drag

I use this code to load line description from .json file and draw the described line on Canvas:

```
<html>
    <head>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="jQuery.js"> </script>
        <script type="text/javascript">
        var canvas;
        var context;
        function Line(x1, y1, x2, y2, color) 
        {
            canvas = document.getElementById("canvas_1");
            context = canvas.getContext("2d");

            this.x1 = x1;
            this.y1 = y1;
            this.x2 = x2;
            this.y2 = y2;
            this.color = color;
        }
        Line.prototype.draw = function() {
            context.beginPath();
            context.moveTo(this.x1, this.y1);
            context.lineTo(this.x2, this.y2);
            context.strokeStyle = this.color;
            context.stroke();
        }
        onload=function simpleExample()
        {
            $(document).ready(function() 
            {
                // draw line with cordinates read from points.json file
                $.getJSON('points.json', function(data)
                {   
                    var line = new Line(data.line.point1.x, data.line.point1.y, data.line.point2.x, data.line.point2.y, data.line.color);
                    line.draw(context);
                });

            });
        }
        </script>
    <head>
    <body>
        <canvas height="500" width="500" id="canvas_1"></canvas>
    </body>
</html>`
```

My points.json file look like this:

```
{
"line": {
    "point1": {
        "x": "50",
        "y": "50"
    },
    "point2": {
        "x": "100",
        "y": "100"
    },
    "color": "red"
}
```

}

Now I want to add ability to move this line on Canvas, but I don't now how. 
I need advice, because my assignment is to load line description from .json file an to draw that line on Canvas(it don't have to be loaded with jQuery as I did, if someone know some other way to do it, please write some example how to do this).

Thanks, 
Aleksandar

Comment: Could you describe in more detail what you mean by moving the line on Canvas? Does the line need to animate? If so, how should it animate?

Comment: The line could be a polyline determined with points. When I drag it it need to be visible during dragging. I resolved problem with simple line defined in .json file like this in my example, but when I have, for example, 3 points that is problem. 
I have an idea to use jQuery to load .json and maybe kineticJS to draw draggable line based on data from json file.